# WebDriver class and ChromeDriver class couldn't be imported

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have added all the files in classpath of library. I am able to see org.openqa.selenium.chrome/ChromeDriver class and org.openqa.selenium/WebDriver class. Still Eclipse is not able to locate the class files. Below is my code.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    }

}
```

Kindly help to resolve. Thanks.

Comment: chromedriver will be an executable... don't import.  Set path using    
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", AbsolutePathToDriver);  Also see: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started

Comment: you can add webdrivers as resources if you want to extract at run-time.

Comment: "I have added all the files in classpath of library." What exactly are "all the files"?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think this is not a simple "import" problem. First you need to set the path for your chrome driver using System.setProperty, just like the example below:

```
@Before
public void BeforeTest() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/driver/chromedriver"); //On windows ...chromedriver.exe
    
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.amazon.com.br");
    
}
```

If you are really having an import problem, maybe something is missing on the classpath. If this is the case I recommend you to use Maven and download the dependencies.